# Plot Projects - Remove notifications from notification centre

Tags: ios, plot, notifications

I'm using Plot Projects for iOS.

When I have finished filtering notifications through the `PlotFilterNotifications` method, I use `filterNotifications.ShowNotifications` to send these notifications to iOS.

The problem is, this doesn't seem to add them to the notification centre in the usual way, as when I check the `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications` call, I get back an empty array. Also none of the usual methods work for removing this from the notification, such as `UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications` or setting the badge count to 0.

I have tried scheduling the notifications manually by taking the notification from the `PlotFilterNotifications` method and bypassing the `filterNotifications.ShowNotifications` method, and cancelling this notification when the user receives an exit notification for the site if the scheduled time has not yet passed, but if a user passes through a site too quickly the notification doesn't get cancelled so I do need to use the built in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You call the method `filterNotifications.ShowNotifications` with all passed notifications in the list, and then try to cancel/clear them straight after that? It is then possible that you try to cancel them before they are sent, since they aren't sent instantly when that method is called. That work is done on a different thread, since it involves some I/O operations.

You could alter the notifications passed to the notification filter to a single notification. Then only that single notification is sent. You change the message and other properties of the notification. A disadvantage would be though that the other notifications aren't considered sent in the statistics.